# UWP - Can I bind a textblock in a datatemplate to a grid column's width outside of it?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Relatively new to UWP, is it possible to bind a `TextBlock` of a `DataTemplate` (used for `ItemTemplate` in a listview) to a column outside of it, or is there any way to set the DataTemplate's grid columns' widths to the size of the "MainGrid"'s column definition widths? Code below to show what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column1" Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column2" Width="8*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column3" Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ListView Name="recordList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind _recordingList, TargetNullValue=0}">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Recording">
            <Grid>
              <TextBlock Grid.Column="{Binding Column1}" Name="TextBlock_Time" Text="{x:Bind Time}"/>
              <TextBlock Grid.Column="{Binding Column2}"  Name="TextBlock_Message" Text="{x:Bind Message}"/>
              <TextBlock Grid.Column="{Binding Column3}"  Name="TextBlock_Type" Text="{x:Bind Type}"/>
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
</Grid>
```

With the image below, I suppose imagine the red lines are the window. Essentially trying to get the columns to adapt to the window size changing.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8M37.png)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? For me it looks like you want to represent the data in some way. Can you make a drawing?

Comment: My goal is a table with items which contain a time, message and the type of message it is. I want them to adapt to the size of the window. I'll work on an image for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move your columns to the template itself.

*DataTemplate* is a scheme that describes what and where. Because it's in *ItemTemplate* , then it means it's for every item.

```
 <ListView Name="recordList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind _recordingList, TargetNullValue=0}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Recording">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column1" Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column2" Width="8*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column3" Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="TextBlock_Time"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="20"
                        Foreground="Red"
                        Text="{x:Bind Time}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="TextBlock_Message"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="20"
                        Foreground="Green"
                        Text="{x:Bind Message}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Name="TextBlock_Type"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="20"
                        Foreground="LightBlue"
                        Text="{x:Bind Type}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

That should make your items look like this.

[image]

Check out documentation, as it's explaining it nicely. There are templates in templates. So you can template a *Container* (how it should display items), and *Items* (how every item should look like).

[Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates)

Remember about *HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"* etc. as this means that the textblock (or **Grid**) will occupy all of it's space available (horizontally). Tinker with it and you'll get a grasp on how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `listviewitem` to be streched to the size of window. To achieve that you need to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` of listviewitem has to set to **stretch** in `ItemContainerStyle`

[image: Image For Reference]

```
<ListView x:Name="MessagesList" BorderThickness="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind _recordingList, TargetNullValue=0}" BorderBrush="Black">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding"  Value="0"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Recording">
           <Grid BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Padding="20" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Time,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
              <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Message,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
              <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{x:Bind Type,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I forgot about setting the item container style, using that with answer above solved my issue.